# SVG image preview issue

Tags: svg, ionic-framework

I have an editor in my ionic 1 app, using which SVG images are getting created.

Below is the SVG image:

[image]

But when I am displaying same image in my app.

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content>
        <img src= "img.svg">
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

It is looking like:

[image]

The text got shifted to left. What can be the issue?

**EDIT : SVG Image:**

```
            <svg width="226.77168" height="226.77168" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <g>
            <title>background</title>
            <rect fill="#ffff00" id="canvas_background" height="228.77168" width="228.77168" y="-1" x="-1"/>
            </g>
            <g id="maingroup">
            <title>Layer 1</title>
            <text height="61.921875" width="110.890625" data-size="5"  class="text_data" autocomplete="false" editable-text="true" text-anchor="start" font-family="Arial" font-size="18.8976377952755" id="svg_1" y="99.93397766491398" x="57.941792488098145" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">
            <tspan dx="0" stroke-width="0" class="helpTspan"/>
            <tspan dx="4.22119140625" data-text="The label is" class="inner-text" stroke-width="0">The label is
            <tspan visibility="hidden"></tspan></tspan>
            <tspan dy="1.05em" dx="-106.66162109375" data-text="or for testing" class="inner-text" stroke-width="0">or for testing
            <tspan visibility="hidden"></tspan></tspan>
            <tspan dy="1.05em" dx="-107.1904296875" data-text="test the text" class="inner-text" stroke-width="0">test the text
            <tspan visibility="hidden"></tspan></tspan>
            </text>
            <path stroke="null" height="137.00021362304688" width="122.99990844726562" class="shape" data-type="shape" data-name="Square" data-id="11" id="svg_4" d="M52.386104583740234,44.885799407958984L52.386104583740234,181.88600158691406L175.38600158691406,181.88600158691406L175.38600158691406,44.885799407958984L52.386104583740234,44.885799407958984L52.386104583740234,44.885799407958984zM170.26231384277344,176.1790008544922L57.50979232788086,176.1790008544922L57.50979232788086,50.59700012207031L170.26231384277344,50.59700012207031L170.26231384277344,176.1790008544922L170.26231384277344,176.1790008544922z" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="null" fill="#000000"/>
            </g>
            </svg>
```

Comment: The picture of the SVG rendering wrong is useful. But we would only be guessing at what's wrong with it. Post the contents of the SVG.

Comment: What devices have you tested on? Does it display wrong on everything?  Does the SVG display wrong on desktop browsers also?

Comment: put your code using  this editor https://stackblitz.com  ,maybe I can help you

Comment: @PaulLeBeau its looking fine on browser but not in android & ios tablets

Comment: @PaulLeBeau please see edit

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are positioning each line of text relative to the **end** of the previous line of text.  It would only take minor differences in the font rendering engines of the mobile browsers to end up with the line of text being a pixel or two shorter or longer. That would mean that the start of the next line would end up in a slight different place.

If this is the problem, then you should be able to avoid it by setting a specific start `x` for each line of text, rather than using `dx`.

Try this version of the file and see if it is any better.

```html
<svg width="226.77168" height="226.77168" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <title>background</title>
    <rect fill="#ffff00" id="canvas_background" height="228.77168" width="228.77168" y="-1" x="-1"/>
  </g>
  <g id="maingroup">
    <title>Layer 1</title>
    <text height="61.921875" width="110.890625" data-size="5"  class="text_data" autocomplete="false" editable-text="true" text-anchor="start" font-family="Arial" font-size="18.8976377952755" id="svg_1" y="99.93397766491398" x="57.941792488098145" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">
      <tspan dx="4.22119140625" data-text="The label is" class="inner-text" stroke-width="0">The label is</tspan>
      <tspan dy="1.05em" x="57.344" data-text="or for testing" class="inner-text" stroke-width="0">or for testing</tspan>
      <tspan dy="1.05em" x="61" data-text="test the text" class="inner-text" stroke-width="0">test the text</tspan>
    </text>
    <path stroke="null" height="137.00021362304688" width="122.99990844726562" class="shape" data-type="shape" data-name="Square" data-id="11" id="svg_4" d="M52.386104583740234,44.885799407958984L52.386104583740234,181.88600158691406L175.38600158691406,181.88600158691406L175.38600158691406,44.885799407958984L52.386104583740234,44.885799407958984L52.386104583740234,44.885799407958984zM170.26231384277344,176.1790008544922L57.50979232788086,176.1790008544922L57.50979232788086,50.59700012207031L170.26231384277344,50.59700012207031L170.26231384277344,176.1790008544922L170.26231384277344,176.1790008544922z" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="null" fill="#000000"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```